# Navigation for pages (not for posts) in Jekyll

Tags: pagination, jekyll

I'm building a website with Jekyll, just with pages.
I want to find a way to generate previous and next links for the pages, with an attribute for the pages like `order`.
Is there something that can do the job (without plugin)? I could only find something about posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% assign sortedPages = site.pages | sort:'order' | where: 'published', true %}

{% for p in sortedPages %}
    {% if p.url == page.url %}
        {% if forloop.first == false %}
            {% assign prevIndex = forloop.index0 | minus: 1 %}
            <a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{sortedPages[prevIndex].url}}">
                previous : {{sortedPages[prevIndex].title}}
            </a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if forloop.last == false %}
            {% assign nextIndex = forloop.index0 | plus: 1 %}
            <a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{sortedPages[nextIndex].url}}">
                next : {{sortedPages[nextIndex].title}}
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This will do the job.

In order to filter which page you publish, you can add a `published` variable in pages front matter.

#### setting the variable

`published: true` -> this is a boolean

`published: 'true'` -> this is a string

#### using where filter

`| where: 'published', true` will test for boolean

`| where: 'published', 'true'` will test for string

Comment: Thanks for that David ! But I don't know : where added the key in your code to filter pages, and how to have just two links and not all my pages' links.

Comment: Ok, I changed my code, but it doesn't work, the front matter of my pages is like that:
`---
layout: page
title: Title of my page
permalink: /part-01/title-of-my-page
order: 12
published: true
---`

Comment: I've edited my answer the right filter is `| where: 'published', true`

Comment: <3 Perfect! Thank you for your explanations!